# How can I satisfy an import of direct_to_template?

Tags: python, django, social-networking, pinax

I am getting an error page from an originally Pinax 0.7 project:

```
ImportError at /
No module named simple
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://stornge.com:8000/
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named simple
Exception Location: /home/jonathan/clay/../clay/urls.py in <module>, line 3
Python Executable:  /home/jonathan/virtual_environment/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    
['/home/jonathan/clay/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pinax/apps',
 '/home/jonathan/clay',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/jonathan/virtual_environment/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']
Server time:    Mon, 25 Mar 2013 13:16:33 -0400
```

The line it is balking on, urls.py:3, is:

```
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
```

How can I change either the import or the area where it's used:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', direct_to_template, {
        "template": "homepage.html",
    }, name="home"),
```

It looks like I can create a view that does a render_to_response() on the homepage, but I'd like to know how I should be solving it, and fall back on that if no one tells me a better way.

Comment: Breadcrumb remark: I made this post as part of a concerted effort to get a Pinax 0.7.3 social project to work with a more recent version of Pinax (for reasons beyond me, the social project in Pinax 1.0.0 is a bare stub, complete with lorem ipsum in the final page). It took me a lot of digging to get to Pinax 0.7.3 (there are innumerable places advertising a free Pinax 0.7.3 download, but I tried dozens and they all pointed to a pinaxproject.com (now) 404. Having found Pinax 0.7.3 and wanting to save other programmers the headache, I have made it available at http://JonathansCorner.com/pinax

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`direct_to_template` has been deprecated. In django 1.5 try using a class based view [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview) in `urls.py`

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='homepage.html'), name="home"),
)
```

There's some information on migrating to version 1.4 (when it was deprecated) [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/).

Comment: Works in Django 1.9

Answer (score 2):

Besides the class-based view `TemplateView`, you can also use the `render` function like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    url(r'^$', lambda request: render(request, 'homepage.html'), name="home"),
)
```