# Django - render HTML template straight from urls.py

Tags: python, django

I have a `Django` app (I'm fairly new so I'm doing my best to learn the ins and outs), where I would like to have a url endpoint simply redirect to a static html file in another folder (app).

My project file hierarchy looks like:

```
docs/
 - html/
    - index.html
myapp/
 - urls.py
```

My `urls.py` looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^docs/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/docs/html/index.html')),
)
```

However, when I navigate to `http://localhost:8000/docs` I see the browser redirect to `http://localhost:8000/docs/html/index.html`, but the page is not accessible.

Is there any reason that the `/docs/html/index.html` would not be avalable to the `myApp` application in a redirect like this?

An pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never tried this with Django, but it seems to me you wouldn't need any normal kit to make a "static" page. Just create a view that responds with a template that doesn't have any context to process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> NOTE: `direct_to_template` has been deprecated since Django 1.5. Use
> [TemplateView.as_view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621048/how-can-i-satisfy-an-import-of-direct-to-template) instead.

I think what you want is a [Template View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/base/#templateview), not a RedirectView. You could do it with something like:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^docs/$', direct_to_template, {
        'template': 'index.html'
    }),
)
```

Just ensure the path to `index.html` is in the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting, or just place it in the `templates` folder of your app ([This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411829/345290) might help).

Comment: dead link for template view.

Comment: This interprets `index.html` as a Django template, not as a static HTML file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure Django is looking for a URL route that matches `/docs/html/index.html`, it does not know to serve a static file, when it can't find the route it is showing an error

Comment: That would make sense. Any way to tell it that it is a static file that you know of?

Comment: STATIFILES_DIR will let you setup the directory

Comment: You could also use a TemplateView for the specific url, many different ways available...