# Convert the Django direct_to_template function to use class based view

Tags: python, django

I am updating a Django project which used the direct_to_template as a function ie:

```
return direct_to_template(request, 'bprofile/init.html', targs)
```

As described a short way down [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views/)

I have seen the [SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621048/how-can-i-satisfy-an-import-of-direct-to-template) and read the [documentation on this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/) which decribe the migration of statements of the form

```
('^about/$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'about.html'})
```

to look like

```
('^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='about.html'))
```

Unfortunatelty I cannot seem to figure out how to change statements from the form that I have into a working new form.

How might one modify this code to work with the new Templateview form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the generic views for this, that's not what they are for. If you want to render a template, you should use the [`render` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render): it takes exactly the same arguments.

```
return render(request, 'bprofile/init.html', targs)
```

Comment: Yep that did it. I just did a simple find and replace on "direct_to_template(" to "render(" and problem solved. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

To use [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) you import TemplateView into your urls.py:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
```

Then you just add the urlconf:

```
('^about/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='bprofile/init.html'))
```